# How to get Date from a resultSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a problem when getting a Date object from a ResultSet. In database it has a value (for example 2014-08-01) and after getting it from resultSet, it has another value (2014-08-31). I know that ResultSet's getDate method returns java.sql.Date, but I tried a few solutions, such as:
    `Date date=new java.util.Date(resultSet.getDate(3).getTime());`
or
   `Date date=resultSet.getTimestamp();` 
but the problem was the same.
If I try
    `Date date=resultSet.getDate();`
It throws a NullPointerException.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: You have to specify the column index or name, `Date date=resultSet.getDate(3);` or `Date date=resultSet.getDate("DATE_COLUMN");`

Comment: The [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5160064/2144390) looks like it might be related. Does its answer help you?

Comment: Just to clarify: Is the "another value" really 2014-08-31 (30 days later) or is it actually 2014-07-31 (the previous day)?

Comment: It is 2014-08-31, 30 days later

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of the column? And confirm this is MySQL as the tag indicates. What *exactly* is the value you input, the value you expected to extract, and the value tha surprised you? Exactly what code did you write to to the INSERT and the SELECT?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case you were not providing the columnName of the Date field to be retrieved.

This should do the job

```
 while (rs.next()) {
    java.sql.Time dbSqlTime = rs.getTime("columnName");
    java.sql.Date dbSqlDate = rs.getDate("columnName");
    java.sql.Timestamp dbSqlTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp("columnName");     
    java.util.Date dbSqlTimeConverted = new java.util.Date(dbSqlTime.getTime());
    java.util.Date dbSqlDateConverted = new java.util.Date(dbSqlDate.getTime());
    System.out.println(dbSqlTimeConverted);
    System.out.println(dbSqlDateConverted);
 }
```

iterate over the `ResultSetObject` get the Date from the `ResultSetObject` which is `java.sql.Date` then convert it to `java.util.Date`

Comment: I find it strange that this is the accepted answer. Not providing the column name would result in a compile time error (as there is no overload that doesn't take a parameter), not in wrong dates, nor would it lead to a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`, because `ResultSet.getDate()` returns an SQL Date, and not a Java one.