# Return extra ".0" when reading "smalldatetime" column with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement, smalldatetime

I have a table in `SQL Server` with a column type `smalldatetime` and I am using `PreparedStatement` to read/write data in my tables. E.g My table is like:

```
|         date           |
+------------------------+
|   2019-11-06 09:48:00  +
|   2019-11-05 07:04:00  +
|         ...            +
+------------------------+
```

and I am reading the column `date` with:

```
String date = rs.getString("date");
```

And I get an extra `.0` at the end of the date:

```
2019-11-06 09:48:00.0
2019-11-05 07:04:00.0
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: why not do a `getDate` then?  Then you can format it to however you want.

Comment: I tried it and `getDate` returns only the date (e.g. 2019-11-06) and not the time...

Comment: @yaylitzis Try using `ResultSet#getTimestamp()` then, and ideally use a `LocalDateTime` on the Java side.

Comment: I tried it and `getTimestamp` also returns the `.0` in the end.. 
I tested with `System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp("date"));`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736427/how-to-get-date-from-a-resultset/24737131

Comment: This looks purely like a formatting thing; the value hasn't been changed its just not being displayed as the OP expects.

Comment: ok thanks @Larnu. As you said, it seems to be just a formatting issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying `SQL Server` JDBC driver converts the returned bytes into a `GregorianCalendar` first and then calls `toString` on a newly created `Timestamp` based on this `GregorianCalendar`. This causes the trailing `.0`.

```java
case CHARACTER: {
  ...many other conversions...
  switch (ssType) {
    case DATETIME: // and SMALLDATETIME
    {
      return (new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis())).toString();
    }
```

[mssql-jdbc Conversion Code](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/9c5cc97f661fe14de11df6be16c8acbc3379d1ff/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/DDC.java#L1050)
[mssql-jdbc SMALLDATETIME handling](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/276d2ca654c6a4315829bab7df499b194cf0f32c/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/IOBuffer.java#L6809)

So what the mssql-jdbc code actually executes is:

```java
System.out.println(new java.sql.Timestamp(100).toString());

> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.1
```

[JavaDoc Timestamp#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--)

Comment: I was not aware that the mssql-jdbc driver is MIT licensed and on github :-)