# The value is incorrect when querying via jdbc driver. why?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, timestamp, timezone

I try to query data from Google BigQuery via JDBC driver, but some values seems to be incorrect.

Steps:

1. Download Simba JDBC driver for googlebigquery freely from https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/jdbc/SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.2.2.1004.zip
2. Loading the driver to your Java App
3. Connect the google query via jdbc
   The sample codes are below:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        String url ="jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;" +
                  "ProjectId=fedjdbc;OAuthType=0;DefaultDataset=jdbc;" +
                  "OAuthServiceAcctEmail=safed-913@fedjdbc.iam.gserviceaccount.com;" +
                    "OAuthPvtKeyPath=/Users/laptop/workspace/bigquery/accounts/fedjdbc-5cb29b8a02fb.json";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            query(conn);
            conn.close();


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void query(Connection conn) {
        String sql = "select * from numbers1";
        sql = "select * from numbers1";
        sql = "select timestamp(\"0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC\") from jdbc.test_date";
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            System.out.println("query begin");
            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
            System.out.println("query end");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                //System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp(1));
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You can find that the result is not "0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000" but "0001-01-03 08:00:00.000000".

Do you know why?

The timezone convert the data locally?

I test it in some hosts with different timezones, same issues.

Comment: I test it with Datadirect driver too which has the same issue.

So, I think, maybe it works as design, but what's the root cause?

If querying the value with equal filter for timezone column, it is incorrect.

Comment: Another test in Google Bigquery UI, it works fine.


i.e, the statement result is correct ("0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC")

Comment: Don't  test with dates at 0001-01-01, you'll run into all kinds of oddities surrounding historic calendar changes, etc. And possibly `getString(..)` does (`getTimestamp(..).toString()`), which given the requirements and implementations of `java.sql.Timestamp` can have additional problems.

Comment: Thanks Mark.
When I use 


Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(1);


to check the details of the value, it seems incorrect too.
i.e, the value is 0001-01-03 08:00:00.0
.
Maybe, it's a historic problem as you said.
Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel could you post your comment as an answer so that the community may benefit from it? Also you could attach this link as example for historical changes in timezones: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127965/why-does-time-zone-have-such-a-crazy-offset-from-utc-on-year-0001-in-postgres

Comment: @Joaquim I don't think it actually answers the question, it was just a hint for a possible direction to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to consider in your code implementation. As @MarkRotteveel mentioned, testing with 0001-01-01 will lead to confusion as there have been multiple historic changes.

BigQuery and the majority of most used software systems work with [tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which aims to record historical time zones and you will find occasional differences compared with UTC. As a test, you can try to query timestamp ‘0001-01-01 America/Los Angeles’ in BigQuery and will get the odd result ‘0001-01-01 07:52:58 UTC”. There is a further explanation in [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127965/why-does-time-zone-have-such-a-crazy-offset-from-utc-on-year-0001-in-postgres).

Regarding your code implementation, you should also consider taking a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736427/how-to-get-date-from-a-resultset/24737131) in order to properly extract the timestamp as it seems that the way you use getString method on the ResultSet could lead to errors.

---